# Replace whole column of a r data.table based on some filtered condition under groupby column

Tags: r, replace, data.table, calculated-columns, data-processing

I have a dataset obtained from a clinical centre monitoring patients with over-weight and high blood sugar.

Basically each patient identified by `patient_id` column, records their initial weights
(`init_weight`) at their time of enrollment (`created_at`).

The patients are expected to revisit clinic at regular interval ( **but surely NOT within 1 day of enrollment** ) in order to record their subsequent weights (`subseq_weight`) against the datetime stamp column `updated_at` .

The column `diff_days` is just difference of `created_at` and `updated_at` in days and and `diff_days_ceil` is the ceiling of `diff_days`, that I created on purpose.

So the datatable looks something like this.

```
   > dt
   patient_id init_weight          created_at subseq_weight
1:         24          77 2018-12-23 07:15:57            72
2:         38          99 2018-12-24 12:13:06           107
3:         38          99 2018-12-24 12:13:06           110
4:         38          99 2018-12-24 12:13:06           115
5:         38          99 2018-12-24 12:13:06           118
6:         47          63 2018-12-27 09:53:40            63
7:         47          63 2018-12-27 09:53:40            64
            updated_at diff_days diff_days_ceil
1: 2018-12-23 07:23:44   0.00541              1
2: 2019-04-02 03:48:20  98.64947             99
3: 2019-02-18 12:23:19  56.00709             57
4: 2019-01-12 11:33:15  18.97233             19
5: 2018-12-24 12:17:44   0.00322              1
6: 2019-01-03 19:08:04   7.38500              8
7: 2018-12-27 10:01:48   0.00565              1
```

Now the issue is , enties in the `init_weight` are not always correct.

If for each patient the `subseq_weight` is found to be within 1 day of `init_weight` entry , then it needs to be replaced with latest `subseq_weight` that has been entered within 1 day.

That means per `patient_id` we need to look for values in the range of 0:1 in `diff_days_ceil` column. If found then the all the `init_weight` records of the patient is to be replaced by the `subseq_weight` value that corresponds to the latest `updated_at` but within 1 day of `created_at`(or in other words that corresponds to `max(diff_days_ceil)` within 1 day).

For an example: Here `patient_id ==24` fulfills such condition as the `subseq_weight` is recorded on the same day of `init_weight`. So 1st row `init_weight` would be replaced with 72.

Same goes for `patient_id` ==47 and all the `init_weight` column entries would be replace by `subseq_weight==64` corresponding to 7th row.

I have tried one approach though totally not sure whether I am losing data or not using this technique.

```
dt[diff_days_ceil %in% 0:1,
   init_weight1 :=  .SD[diff_days_ceil %in% 0:1, subseq_weight[which.max(diff_days)]],
   .(patient_id)]

dt[,init_weight1 := nafill(x = init_weight1,type = 'nocb'),.(patient_id)]
```

In the first part i have created one new column `init_weight1` for the records where `subseq_weight` is within 1 day of `init_weight` entry.

In the second part all the other cases, being `NA`s , are filled using "*next observation carried backward*" technique for each `patient_id`.

I would like to have some alternative technique where this NA creation and then filling could be avoided.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no NA in any column. Please explain more on the second part. Give an example like the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[diff_days <= 1, init_weight := subseq_weight, by = .(patient_id)]
df

#   patient_id init_weight          created_at subseq_weight          updated_at
#1:         24          72 2018-12-23 07:15:57            72 2018-12-23 07:23:44
#2:         38          99 2018-12-24 12:13:06           107 2019-04-02 03:48:20
#3:         38          99 2018-12-24 12:13:06           110 2019-02-18 12:23:19
#4:         38          99 2018-12-24 12:13:06           115 2019-01-12 11:33:15
#5:         38         118 2018-12-24 12:13:06           118 2018-12-24 12:17:44
#6:         47          63 2018-12-27 09:53:40            63 2019-01-03 19:08:04
#7:         47          64 2018-12-27 09:53:40            64 2018-12-27 10:01:48
#   diff_days diff_days_ceil
#1:   0.00541              1
#2:  98.64947             99
#3:  56.00709             57
#4:  18.97233             19
#5:   0.00322              1
#6:   7.38500              8
#7:   0.00565              1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(patient_id = c(24L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 47L, 47L
), init_weight = c(77L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 63L, 63L), created_at = c("2018-12-23 07:15:57", 
"2018-12-24 12:13:06", "2018-12-24 12:13:06", "2018-12-24 12:13:06", 
"2018-12-24 12:13:06", "2018-12-27 09:53:40", "2018-12-27 09:53:40"
), subseq_weight = c(72L, 107L, 110L, 115L, 118L, 63L, 64L), 
    updated_at = c("2018-12-23 07:23:44", "2019-04-02 03:48:20", 
    "2019-02-18 12:23:19", "2019-01-12 11:33:15", "2018-12-24 12:17:44", 
    "2019-01-03 19:08:04", "2018-12-27 10:01:48"), diff_days = c(0.00541, 
    98.64947, 56.00709, 18.97233, 0.00322, 7.385, 0.00565), diff_days_ceil = c(1L, 
    99L, 57L, 19L, 1L, 8L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```